# How does Godzilla receive this energy in Godzilla: King of the Monsters?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-king-of-the-monsters

In ***Godzilla: King of the Monsters*** we see that:

> Mothra dies and transfers her energy to Godzilla.

How does this happen? How does Godzilla receive this energy? Is it possible that any other Titan can transfer energy to others or just Mothra has this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier in the movie Godzilla is shown both absorbing ambient radiation to heal and also absorbing a nuclear blast to power himself up. It's pretty clear Legendary Godzilla can absorb radiation to strengthen himself. Mothra, as a Titan, probably also consumes radiation and can generate energy blasts. If she converted herself into some kind of energy form it's plausible Godzilla consumed that energy. We've seen Ghidorah consuming power from a city, MUTOs being drawn by radiation, so it seems likely that at least some Titans have a similar ability.